# css3 automatic browser compatibility fixer

Tags: css, cross-browser

Does anybody knows website that will automaticaly fix my css for more browser compatibility

For example: if in my css is written

```
div 
{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Convert to

```
div
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vendor prefix JS for this http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/